# Copy Rotation to Only Z Axis Not Working as Expected

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones, constraints

[image: Rotate only on Z Axis]

I'm trying to get the selected ring in this picture to only rotate on its Z axis whilst tracking the lower mounting to the leg.

What should happen is that the ring rotates so that the hydraulic, which is targeted to the UV sphere mounting on the ring, has the least angle - ie has shortest distance to the ring. The idea is that I am trying to make model look like the ring is driving leg rotation and the pistons (there will be 3 or 4 of them) are driving extension and flexion.

- The closest I have come is using the constraint **"Locked Track"**. The fixed axis is Z, and the only version that seems to work is -Y. Testing it, when rotating the armature bone in pose mode along the Z axis, the ring should hardly move, but it spins almost 180 degrees.
- **Copy rotation** does not work either.
- I have tried **damped tracking**, and **track to**. Neither work, but they aren't right for that job.
- I tried using two locked track constraints and that didn't give me the results either.
- I tried parenting an armature to the "bone" - not an armature but a metal model bone connecting the leg with the hip joint, and then taking rotation info from that, but that did not result in what I was looking for either.

What I am looking for is the world rotation of the lower mounting (called rivet v2 in my blend file) to only affect the local Z of the ring so that the parented hydraulics rotate to the shortest distance. It's proving to be extremely tricky.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking at, but I clicked all the answers that helped me, or even the ones that contributed to my finding the solution myself. Some of them didn't receive answers, and some didn't help.

Edit - actually there are couple of questions I received responses that I did not mark up.

Comment: You can Upvote answers and comments that you find useful, but you should ACCEPT (using the tick mark) any answers that directly solve your problem (one answer per question).

Comment: unfortunately we don't see the picture with the selected ring anymore...

Comment: Where can I find the tick mark? Sorry about the lost image...I'll try to fix.

Comment: thanks for editing your question. But honestly - i still don't get it how the movement should look like. And because you didn't get any answer in 5 hours i think other people are also struggling. So i would suggest to improve your question by a sketch/picture who clearly show how the movement should be. A picture explains more than 1000 words...maybe 2 or three pictures with a different angle of the leg and how the ring should be?

Comment: Yep, I was looking at it as well, downloaded the file and stared at it for a while... I have no idea, what movement is the goal. :D

Comment: Ok I'll have another go in the morning. The closest I can get to the movement I am looking for is with Locked Track, Track Axis = Y, and Locked Axis = Z. With the Target "Rivet v2", and setting the influence to 0.2. I am trying to get the highlighted Ring to only rotate along the "Z" axis so that it follows "Rivet v2" with the least rotation. It does do it correctly for part of the rotation, but then it spins around nearly 180, causing the hydraulics to twist. I just want the rotation inherited by the Rivet v2 from animation to be transferred to the Z axis of the Ring.